# ng-click not working in manually loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON file that contains the page content I wish to load. In it, I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a data-ng-click='foo()'>Bar</a>
```

When I load the page content into the page as HTML:

```
<p class="body" ng-bind-html="jsonText | raw"></p>
```

using this filter:

```
app.filter('raw', function ($sce) {
    return function (input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
});
```

the link does not trigger `foo()` call on click. Is what I'm trying to do impossible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using filter for this is not a good idea, because you need to `$compile` the loaded HTML and for that you need `$scope`. So, you either need to `$compile` it manually and put the result in `$scope` yourself, or create a directive instead of a filter:

```
.directive('dynamicHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch($attrs.dynamicHtml, function (html) {
                $element.empty().append($compile(html)($scope));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and use it instead of `ngBindHtml`:

```
<p dynamic-html="jsonText"></p>
```

Just be aware that by compiling the HTML yourself, you're completely bypassing [contextual escaping](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/service/$sce), so you should only do it with your own, secure content.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, how would you use this in the html? As an attribute to a div?

Comment: Figured it out, you literally just replace one call with the other. Awesome solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your adding a plain text into DOM. Your filter will just ad an piece of html text which includes the ng-click directive which as far as the browser is concerned, it is just an attribute it cannot understand.

You need to compile the template using the $compile service before injecting it into the dom