# Render angular code within a ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm trying to render github readme's using remarkable and angular. Everything related to parsing the markdown is working properly but unfortunately the product owner has some more wishes for the application.

He wants to be able to put youtube video's and html forms in the readme. I'm currently using the [Youtube-embed directive](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) made by [Brandly](https://github.com/brandly) but unfortunately it does not render in our page.

I am using a script which uses `ng-bind-html` in combination with `$sce.trustAsHtml` in order to parse html in the page. Normal HTML is picked up just fine (form tags and other stuff) but angular stuff (youtube directive as example) aren't.

I also noticed that angular directives such as `ng-click`, `ng-submit` etc aren't working.
Does anyone know how to make angular work in html which is bieing parsed within the angular application using `ng-bind-html`?

Here is a code example on how the html is bieing parsed to the template:

JS:

```
case 'markdown':
    $scope.fileContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(remarkable.render(content));
break;
```

HTML:

```
<pre class="fileContent"><code ng-bind-html="fileContent"></code></pre>
```

i've added a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mC30KRTzyutW1rPYuvxe?p=preview) with the problem I am having, as you can see it never executes the `ng-submit` that I  added in the form.

~ Archcry

Comment: Did you try to compile the html? see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I tried ```$compile``` yesterday but it seems like it only works in directives or something, I can't really find a good example on the internet with ```$compile```.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-click not working in manually loaded HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428308/ng-click-not-working-in-manually-loaded-html)

Comment: Might be a duplicate for I don't quite understand how to make a directive take care of this. Isn't it possible without using a directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the example directive from the angular site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

```
angular.module('compileExample', [], function($compileProvider) {
    // configure new 'compile' directive by passing a directive
    // factory function. The factory function injects the '$compile'
    $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
      // directive factory creates a link function
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
             // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function(value) {
            // when the 'compile' expression changes
            // assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
            // scope.
            // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
            // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        );
      };
    });
  })
  .controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Angular';
    $scope.html = 'Hello {{name}}';
  }]);
```

Then you can use it as in

```
<p compile="fileContent"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem, I did not expect it to be this simple. :D